# Inconsistent types 7481 - SQL case when and group by

Tags: sql, excel, group-by, case-when

Wondering if someone can help me out. I had this query working recently and have just added in some case when measures to reduce the processing in Excel. The database is an ODBC. Now when i try to return the data i get the error of Inconsistent types 7481. Can anyone help me out please. Sorry i have only just started really using SQL so a lot of this is new to me.

```
    SELECT 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
, SUM(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciInvoiceApproved) AS 'Approved' 
, SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS 'Prepared'
, SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS 'Pending'
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanySiteID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
, Sum(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciTotalNettValue) As 'Total Nett Value'
, Sum(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciVatValue) AS 'VAT Value'

FROM

SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
, SBS.PUB.InvoiceCreditItem InvoiceCreditItem_0

WHERE

InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanyID = Company_0.CompanyID
AND (Company_0.CoaCompanyName<>'ATOS')
AND InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate >= ?


GROUP BY Company_0.CoaCompanyName, InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanySiteID , InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
```

Comment: (Unrelated) Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY Company_0.CoaCompanyName, InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanySiteID
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate`.

Comment: Hello Jarlh 

I have updated as you suggested but unfortunately i still get the error of 7481 inconsistent types  please see updated query above

Comment: You have to locate the issue. Divide and conquer - i.e. remove some of your query and see in the error remains or not, until you find the problem construction.

Comment: I have done it for some reason it didn't like , SUM(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciInvoiceApproved) AS 'Approved'  i think i know how to get around this though. thank your help and advice today big confidence boost in my ability. Is there somewhere i can up vote you?

Comment: Well, check my profile and perhaps upvote one of my answers?